# В чём заключается ошибка DetailView is missing a QuerySet

Tags: python, django

В ходе изучения учебника Django 2.1 возникла ошибка. Нужно написать контроллер DetailView для выведения страницы со сведениями о выбранном объявлении, и как только нажимаешь на ссылку с этими сведениями выдаёт ошибку StoryDetailView is missing a QuerySet. Как это исправить. 
Вот код файлов:

```
views.py
from .models import Story, Rubric
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailVie

class StoryDetailView(DetailView):
models = Story

def get_context_data(self, *args,**kwargs):
    context=super().get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
    context['rubrics']=Rubric.objects.all()
    return context



urls.py
from .views import add_and_save, StoryDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    path('detail/<int:pk>/',StoryDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),


bb_detail.html
{% extends 'layout/basic.html'%}

{%block title%}{{bb.title}}{%endblock%}
{%block content%}
<p>Рубрика:{{bb.rubric.name}}</p>
<h2>{{bb.title}}</h2>
<p>{{bb.content}}</p>
<p>Цена:{{bb.price}}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```python
class StoryDetailView(DetailView):
    models = Story
```

замени на

```python
class StoryDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Story
```

у вас **одна** модель, а не несколько :-)

или

```python
class StoryDetailView(DetailView):
    queryset = Story.objects
```